# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4 [error in intellij]

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting error in intellij for java project while running junit test.

`java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4` error in intellij.

it was working perfectly fine but with some intellij upgrade it has stopped working,
However maven clean install from command prompt still works fine.
But cant do junit from intellij as it gives

```
 java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4.
```

Not finding any solution for this
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278990
Intellij version
IU-211.7142.45, JRE 11.0.10+9-b1341.41x64 JetBrains s.r.o., OS Windows 10(amd64) v10.0

This is not code problem.
Its giving problem with any basic test but only through intellij when i do right click and run junit test.

Comment: Please clarify what's throwing that error. Is it Maven, your JUnit test (i.e. your own code), or IntelliJ itself? Whatever the answer, it would be best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Slaw updated now.its intellij specific.It was all working good since 1 year on previous version of intellij

Comment: The solution for me was to delete my Intellij settings and and set up Intellij again from scratch.

Comment: The solution for me was to remove the `:` inside the `<name>` tag of my `pom.xml`. Ref. [IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284113?_ga=2.89531036.626209883.1640120538-100587871.1621612233&_gac=1.226515439.1638558535.Cj0KCQiAnaeNBhCUARIsABEee8Uq6y_0GTysfOHZGYjcQqHsy_ULqnMbSYNWQ9Oa5OgcXEikni9rOMMaApliEALw_wcB).

Comment: If you use maven, there is a workaround. go to settings > build tools > maven > runner > and check the  "delegate IDE build/run actions to maven"

It will be horribly slow, but you may survive until jetbrains fixes it.

Comment: This error can happen in Android Studio for Windows, when trying to load an Android Gradle project. You will see error: `java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <"> at index 0: "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\"` . The fix is to remove all `"` speech mark characters in your `JAVA_HOME` system environment variable. More info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO7iU.png

Comment: @Mr-IDE error is ":" not "